# Is there a way to check whether a stream is finite in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I know there is **infinite** stream in Java.

**Is there a way to check whether the stream is finite or not?**

Something like this method `isStreamFinite(Stream<T> stream)`?

```
@Test
public void testStreamFinity() {
    assertFalse(isStreamFinite(generateLong()));
}

private <T> boolean isStreamFinite(Stream<T> stream) {
    if (stream.count() < Long.MAX_VALUE) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private Stream<Long> generateLong() {
    return LongStream.generate(() -> new Random().nextLong()).boxed();
}
```

The construction of the **Stream** would leave some *marks/tracks* that we can use to trace back to check it?

The **checking method** could work always as expected reliably?

### Update

I was wrong about this when trying to solve a problem by detecting the `isFinite` of a stream. It seems it's not stable/reliable as the answers mentioned. I will refactor my solution in another around. Thank you for the help ~

Comment: c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem It's not possible to solve generically. Only determine how the stream was constructed.

Comment: Does your method return?

Comment: Hahah, of course no ~ it's just a demo to provide what I am trying to do.

Comment: I *think* that there could have been a flag introduced when it is absolutely known that a certain stream is infinite, like `generate` for example; but what would be the real value in this? And how about `Files.lines` for example, is your file a "finite" one? I can't tell why there would be a need to have this. Also `Long.MAX_VALUE` is reported in numerous other cases too, besides an infinite stream...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no reliable way to do it. Even using the `estimateSize`, which is documented:

> ... or returns Long.MAX_VALUE if infinite, unknown, or too expensive to compute.

So simply relying on the fact that `Long.MAX_VALUE` will tell you if this stream is infinite or not - is simply wrong.

The other suggestion says that to use `SIZED`, which is again wrong:

```
IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(5)
```

You *know* that this is a `SIZED` stream - the implementation does not and will *not* report the sized flag.

Bottom-line: you can't in a reliable way. Theoretically this could be possible for some cases, like when you *just* use `generate` without limiting or short-circuiting the stream, the implementation could register a flag like `IS_INFINITE` or something, but this IMO would be useless, probably for 99% of the cases.

You can also think in reverse here, how about when you want to tell with certainty if this stream is finite? In such a case, `getExactSizeIfKnown()` would tell you that.

Comment: And don’t forget, nobody knows whether `IntStream.generate(() -> 1) .takeWhile(x -> externalCondition(x))` is finite…

Comment: Well, if there was an `IS_INFINITE` flag, it allowed the implementation to turn the `IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(5)` example into a `SIZED` stream. But for external code, it would not have much use as the absence of this flag still doesn’t guaranty that the stream is finite.

Comment: @Holger It seems it's much more complicated than I thought. I will refactor my solution. Thank you ~

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to check if a stream is infinite with certainty, but there is a way to detect if it's finite with certainty.

[fixed] I had it the wrong way around.

```
/**
 * When this returns {@code true}, the stream is finite for sure. Otherwise the
 * stream could be either infinite or finite.
 */
private static <T> boolean isStreamFinite(Stream<T> stream) {
    return stream.spliterator().estimateSize() != Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Javadoc of `estimateSize()`:

> Returns an estimate of the number of elements that would be encountered by a `forEachRemaining` traversal, or returns `Long.MAX_VALUE` if infinite, unknown, or too expensive to compute.

Comment: this is probably the best guess there is, but still just a guess, there is no reliable way to do it

Comment: You can use `getExactSizeIfKnown() >= 0` to detect when it is definitely finite.